# RevisionID may not be empty inserting purchase order

Tags: acumatica

Hi I am creating a process to insert a purchase order but I have hit an error I cant resolve.  When I persist my purchase order I get an error RevisionID may not be empty.  I am confused and RevisionID does not appear on any of the DAC's POOrder or POLine.

Here is the error

```
Message: Error #4: 'RevisionID' may not be empty.

Date/Time: 18/06/2015 12:22
Platform: 
Browser: 

Source: PX.Data
Target Site: Boolean MoveNext()
Stack Trace:    at PX.Data.PXDefaultAttribute.RowPersisting(PXCache sender,  PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowPersisting(Object item, PXDBOperation operation)
at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistInserted(Object row)
at PX.Objects.CS.SharedRecordAttribute.RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowPersisting(Object item, PXDBOperation operation)
at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistInserted(Object row)
at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persist(PXDBOperation operation)
at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist(Type cacheType, PXDBOperation operation)
at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist()
at PX.Objects.PO.POOrderEntry.Persist()
at PX.Data.PXSave`1.<Handler>d__4.MoveNext()
at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__c.MoveNext()
at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__c.MoveNext()
at PX.Data.PXAction`1.Press()
at    Exosoft.MP.MikePero.Graphs.GeneratePurchaseOrdersProcess.GeneratePurchaseOrders (List`1 sOrderLines) in c:\Projects\Exosoft\Mike Pero Rex  Integration\Dev\Main\Source\MP\MikePero\Graphs\Processes\GeneratePurchaseOrdersProcess.cs:line 102
```

And here my code for creating the purchase order (unfinished)

```
        private static void GeneratePurchaseOrders(List<PX.Objects.SO.SOLineCustom> sOrderLines)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime firstOfMonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1);
            DateTime lastOfMonth = firstOfMonth.AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1);

            foreach (PX.Objects.SO.SOLineCustom soLine in sOrderLines) {
                POOrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<POOrderEntry>();
                graph.Clear(PXClearOption.ClearAll);

                PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem item = AdvancedMethods.GetInventoryItemByInventoryID(soLine.InventoryID);
                PX.Objects.AP.VendorR vendor = AdvancedMethods.GetVendorByID(item.PreferredVendorID);

                if (vendor == null) return;

                PX.Objects.CR.Location vLocation = AdvancedMethods.GetLocationByLocationID(vendor.DefLocationID);

                if (vLocation == null) return;

                //Get Existing Current Months Purchase Order
                PX.Objects.PO.POOrder pOrder = PXSelect<PX.Objects.PO.POOrder, 
                    Where<PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.vendorID, Equal<Required<PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.vendorID>>,
                        And<Where<PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.orderDate, Greater<Required<PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.orderDate>>,
                            And<PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.orderDate, LessEqual<Required<PX.Objects.PO.POOrder.orderDate>>>>>>>.Select(new PXGraph(), item.PreferredVendorID, firstOfMonth, lastOfMonth);

                if (pOrder == null)
                {
                    //Add new purchase order
                    pOrder = new PX.Objects.PO.POOrder();
                    pOrder.OrderType = PX.Objects.PO.POOrderType.RegularOrder;
                    pOrder = PXCache<PX.Objects.PO.POOrder>.CreateCopy(graph.Document.Insert(pOrder));                       
                    pOrder.VendorID = vendor.ID;
                    pOrder.VendorLocationID = vendor.DefLocationID;
                    pOrder.SiteID = soLine.SiteID;
                    pOrder.OrderDesc = "Generated Purchase Order";
                    pOrder.OrderDate = lastOfMonth;
                    pOrder.TermsID = vendor.TermsID;
                }

                graph.Document.Current = graph.Document.Search<POOrder.orderNbr>(pOrder.OrderNbr, pOrder.OrderType);

                graph.vendor.Current = vendor;
                graph.location.Current = vLocation;



                //Add Line to Purchase Order
                PX.Objects.PO.POLine pLine = new PX.Objects.PO.POLine();
                pLine.LineType = POLineType.Service;
                pLine.OrderType = pOrder.OrderType;

                pLine.RequestedDate = soLine.ShipDate;
                pLine.VendorID = pOrder.VendorID;
                pLine.VendorLocationID = pOrder.VendorLocationID;
                pLine.InventoryID = soLine.InventoryID;
                pLine.SubItemID = pLine.SubItemID;
                pLine.SiteID = soLine.SiteID;
                pLine.UOM = soLine.UOM;
                pLine.OrderQty = soLine.Qty;
                pLine.TranDesc = soLine.TranDesc;
                pLine.ProjectID = soLine.ProjectID;
                pLine.TaskID = soLine.TaskID;

                pLine.UnitCost = soLine.UnitCost;
                pLine.CuryUnitCost = soLine.CuryUnitCost;

                pLine = graph.Transactions.Insert(pLine);

                graph.Save.Press();

            }//foreach


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorHandling.LogError(ex);
            throw new PXException(String.Format("An error occurred generating purchase orders: {0}", ex.Message));
        }
    }

}//GeneratePurchaseOrdersProcess
```

Comment: At which line of code this error message happens?

Comment: graph.save.press();  I have since changed it to graph.actions.presssave() but I get the same error

Answer (score 2):

Ok I forgot to update the purchase order after I changed properties

pOrder = graph.Document.Update(pOrder);